# Read file data continuously in python

Tags: python

i have one file and contain some data

```
 Net Name:  VDD
 Pin Name:  VDD
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4605e-03 

 Net Name:  VDD
 Pin Name:  VDD
 Instance Name:  ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen1

 Layer/Via#  PGResistor  Resistance(cumulative) Ohm  Voltage_Drop(cumulative) V  Length 
 VSRC       N 0.0000e+00 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03 3.7865e-03  0  144.43150,550.00000   
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 1.0000e-06 0.0000e+00 3.7865e-03  0.000100000001  144.43150,550
 AP         N 3.1474e-03 3.1484e-03 5.6028e-06 3.7921e-03  6.8432998  144.43200,550.0000
 AP         N 1.0000e-06 3.1494e-03 0.0000e+00 3.7921e-03  0.000200000003  144.43200,543
 AP         N 1.9433e-03 5.0927e-03 1.1802e-05 3.8039e-03  4.1663999  144.43200,543.1565
 AP         N 2.5653e-03 7.6580e-03 1.7583e-05 3.8215e-03  5.5001001  144.43200,538.9900
 AP         N 1.0137e-02 1.7795e-02 7.0572e-05 3.8921e-03  8.851  144.43200,533.49000   
 AP         N 2.1164e-02 3.8959e-02 1.5050e-04 4.0426e-03  16.0295  144.43200,524.63900 
 AP         N 9.9838e-07 3.8960e-02 0.0000e+00 4.0426e-03  0.054  128.40250,524.63900   
 RV         N 3.3405e-02 7.2365e-02 2.3925e-04 4.2818e-03  2.7  128.40250,524.69300   
 M15        N 9.9838e-07 7.2366e-02 0.0000e+00 4.2818e-03  0.6985  128.40250,524.69300  
 M15        N 1.0580e-01 1.7817e-01 4.3488e-04 4.7167e-03  14.947  127.70400,524.69300  
 VIA14      N 8.8155e-03 1.8698e-01 5.1737e-05 4.7684e-03  0.324  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 3.5033e-02 2.2201e-01 1.1855e-04 4.8870e-03  4.96  127.70400,539.64000   
 M14        N 1.6951e-01 3.9153e-01 1.3857e-03 6.2727e-03  24  132.66400,539.64000   
 M9         N 9.5367e-07 6.2670e+00 0.0000e+00 7.4605e-03  0.26  187.49200,516.86300 
      
 Layer/Via  Resistance(Ohm)  Voltage_Drop(V)  R_Cumulative(Ohm)  Vdrop_Cummulative(V) 
 VSRC        0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03  0.0000e+00  3.7865e-03 
 AP          3.8960e-02  2.5606e-04  3.8960e-02  4.0426e-03 
 RV          3.3405e-02  2.3925e-04  7.2365e-02  4.2818e-03 
 M15         1.0580e-01  4.3488e-04  1.7817e-01  4.7167e-03 
 VIA14       8.8155e-03  5.1737e-05  1.8698e-01  4.7684e-03 
 M9          2.2392e+00  5.8532e-05  6.2670e+00  7.4655e-03
```

the file data will repeat with **Net Name** and **Pin Name** as **VDD,VSS,VDDA,VSSA. so on..**

I Want to skip the **DATA** after **Layer/Via#** till before **Layer/Via** and i want to consider only **M9** data after the Layer/Via with the last value **" eg: 7.4605e-03,7.4655e-03 "**

The logic i tried

```
def readPinFile(filename): 

    result = None
    with open(filename, "r") as file:   
        flag_count = 0
        flag_count1 = 0
        result = {}
        result1 = {}
        lastPin = None        
        for line in file:
            lines = line.strip()
            
            if lines[-3:] == "VDD": 
                Pin = lines.split(" ")[3]          
                result[Pin] = {"INST": None, "M9": None}

            if lines[-3:] == "VSS": 
                Pin = lines.split(" ")[3]               
                result[Pin] = {"INST": None, "M9": None}    
 
                
            if lines[:9] == "Instance ":
                result[Pin]["INST"] = lines.split(" ")[3]
            
            if lines.startswith("Layer/Via "):
               flag_count1 = 1
           
            if lines[:2] == "M9" and flag_count1 == 1:
               result[Pin]["M9"] = lines.split(" ")[14]
             
          

    return result
pin_of_file1 = readPinFile("inst_1.txt") 

for pin, pin_data in pin_of_file1.items():
   # pass 
    print(pin_data)
```

This block i used because of this file contain net and pin name as **VSS** (above data just for example **net name** and **pin name** will change every block and format is same)

```
if lines[-3:] == "VSS": 
     Pin = lines.split(" ")[3]               
     result[Pin] = {"INST": None, "M9": None}
```

same logic I used for other programs to handle file data and its working as a loop there here it's not working as a loop
Expected output

```
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'inst': 'ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'inst': 'ld_slice_logic_wrap_inst/ld_slice_logic_top_inst/ld_clk_gen_top_inst/ld_wdqs_clk_gen', 'M9': '7.4655e-03'}
```

the output that I am getting is

```
{'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'Net_Name': 'VSS', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}
```

can anyone please guide me to come out of this?

Answer (score 0):

```
def readPinFile(filename):

    result = None
    overall_result = None
    with open(filename, "r") as file:
        flag_count = 0
        flag_count1 = 0
        result = {}
        result1 = {}
        lastPin = None
        for line in file:
            lines = line.strip()

            if lines[-3:] == "VDD":
                Pin = lines.split(" ")[3] + str(flag_count)
                result[Pin] = {"INST": None, "M9": None}

            if lines[-3:] == "VSS":
                Pin = lines.split(" ")[3]
                result[Pin] = {"INST": None, "M9": None}

            if lines[:9] == "Instance ":
                result[Pin]["INST"] = lines.split(" ")[3]

            if lines.startswith("Layer/Via "):
                flag_count1 = 1

            if lines[:2] == "M9" and flag_count1 == 1:
                result[Pin]["M9"] = lines.split(" ")[14]
                flag_count1 = 0
                flag_count = flag_count + 1

    return result


pin_of_file1 = readPinFile("inst_1.txt")

for pin, pin_data in pin_of_file1.items():
    # pass
    print(pin_data)
```

Comment: After adding couple of lines to your code it started working .

Answer (score 0):

You may find this approach more robust:

```
def readPinFile(filename):
    values = []
    inLayer = False
    d = {}
    with open(filename) as data:
        for line in map(str.strip, data):
            if not inLayer:
                for k1, k2 in ('Net Name:', 'Net_Name'), ('Pin Name:', 'Pin_Name'):
                    if line.startswith(k1):
                        d[k2] = line.split()[-1]
                        continue
            if len(tokens := line.split()) > 1:
                if tokens[0] == 'Layer/Via':
                    inLayer = True
                elif inLayer and tokens[0] == 'M9':
                    d['M9'] = tokens[-1]
                    values.append(d)
                    d = {}
                    inLayer = False
    return values
```

**Output:**

```
[{'Net_Name': 'VDD', 'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'M9': '7.4605e-03'}, {'Net_Name': 'VDD', 'Pin_Name': 'VDD', 'M9': '7.4655e-03'}]
```